# Swift. Init no longer required?

Tags: swift, syntax, initialization

In swift, initialization such as below is no longer required right? A lot of talk about this topic, but there seems to be no clear answer. Thanks in advance!!

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: The above isn't required in Objective-C.

Comment: Which part are you asking about? a) `init` method itself, b) `[super init]`, or c) `if (self = ...`?

Answer (score 1):

Correct — sort of.

If you're implementing a no-parameters initializer for a class, and it's the designated initializer for that class (you're not declaring it `convenience init`), not only is there no need to call `super` and/or assign to self, you *can't*. The initialization chain is enforced by the language, so it does for you the parts that you don't need to do.

If you're subclassing, any initializer you implement *must* delegate to the delegated initializer of the superclass. But you don't assign to `self`, you just call `super.init(/*whatever*/)` — during class initialization, the identity of `self` is fixed and cannot change. (Otherwise it'd be possible for a superclass' state to get left uninitialized.)

Because initializers are not functions/methods in Swift, they don't have a return value, so there's no `return self` at the end, either. Again, the language does the required parts (creating an instance of the class) for you — inside your initializer, all you do is set up the state required in your class.

See [Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID216) in *The Swift Programming Language* for details.